# SugarCRM Logic for Adding VAT to Total Cost if Checkbox Checked

Tags: logic, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I’m new to SugarLogic and SugarCRM. I’m trying to add logic to a field. Basically I have a VAT checkbox field and if it’s ticked I want the total cost field to be multiplied by 23%. If its not ticked, then VAT isn’t added. I will be grateful for any help given. The below code will not work for me.

```
ifElse(equal($vat_applicable,true),multiply($total_cost,0.023))
```

Thanks x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an “if/else” SugarLogic function, you need to complete the rest of the formula (else). Add this formula to the 'total cost' field.

```
ifElse(equal($vat_applicable,true),
    multiply($total_cost,0.23),
    $total_cost
)
```

Comment: Hey Karl Thanks for your help I am getting an invalid formula error saying The formula must be of typeboolean, I dont understand why when im using the boolean "true"

Comment: What version of SugarCRM or SuiteCRM are you using? Do you have a screenshot of adding the formula to the field?

Comment: Im using SugarCRM 7. The vat applicable field is a checkbox, i think that is the problem the code works when i use it in a currency field for example my agreed_pm_fee. Im wondering if i should add the code to the total_cost calculation .... so it should look something like this maybe.             '           ifElse(equal($vat_applicable,true),
multiply($total_cost,0.23),
$total_cost
)
ifElse(equal($vat_applicable,false),
add($mileage_cost,$mileage_cost,$accommodation_cost,$cost)
$total_cost
)'

Comment: I used my formula on a Currency field within SugarCRM Version 7.6.1.0.

Comment: Hi Karl your code worked for me thanks for your help just wondering in the total_cost_ field that i added your code to how would you say total cost = mileage + time+ hotel_ stay = SUM THEN IFELSE "YOUR ABOVE CODE" i Know it looks something like this add(mileage, time, hotel_ stay)

Comment: Without those fields available to me it's tough. ifElse(equal($vat_applicable,true), multiply($total_cost,0.23), add($mileage_cost, $time_cost, $accommodation_cost)). Which in English is: 1) If there’s applicable VAT, then multiply the total cost by %23, 2) If there isn’t, add $mileage_cost, $time_cost, $accommodation_cost. Is that what you mean?